# Is there a general way to calculate the asymptotic time complexity of for loops with step?

Tags: algorithm, loops, time-complexity

Is there a general way/approach/methodology to calculate the asymptotic time complexity of such loops?

```
j=a
while j<n do
    j=f(j)
```

where `f(j)` could be `j+1`, `2*j`, `j*j` etc..

Note that the above code is equivalent to the C for-loop

```
for (j=a; j<n; j=f(j));
```

Comment: general way is to _know_ what `f` is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach is by solving the recurrence

```
F(j+1) = f(F(j)), F(0) = a.
```

then solving the inequation

```
F(k(n)) < n <= F(k(n)+1),
```

for `k(n)`, and the complexity is `O(k(n))`.

For example, `f(j):= j²` yields

```
F(j+1) = F²(j), F(0)= a
```

which has the solution

```
F(j) = a^(2^j).
```

Then by inversion

```
k(n) ~ log(log(n)/log(a))/log(2) = O(log(log(n))).
```

Comment: Uhm.. what is the meaning of the F function? And how can j can be a function of n? Could you explain some more?

Comment: `F` is the `j`th iterate of `f(a)`. I will change the notation about `j` for better rigor.

Answer (score 2):

First the answers, then the general approach:

1) If f(j) = j + 1, then you will have roughly n steps to reach n.

2) If it is 2*j. Each time you are doubling it so in roughly log n steps you will reach n.

3) If j*j, it will a, a^2, a^4, a^8; hence, in roughly loglog n steps you will get to n.

Now, what is the general way? you find the pattern and equal it to n and then solve the equation:

1) Applying f x times will give you a + x, so a + x = n so x = n - a = O(n).

2) Applying f x times will give you a*(2^x), so a*(2^x) = n, so x = log n/a = O(log n).

3) Applying f x times will give you a^(2^x), so a^(2^x) = n so 2^x = log_a n, so x = log log_a n = O(log log n). (log_a n is log of n with base a)

I hope it helps